# how to get select option based on value

Tags: jquery

How would I get a select option based on a value of that option.

for example:

```
<select>
  <option>option1</option>
  <option>option2</option>
  <option>option3</option>
</select>
```

I want to  find option2 based on the value.

```
var temp = "option2"; 
$(select).get(temp);
```

so i'm using get() as an example of what I want to do I know there isn't a get for that but I want it to return option2 as a jquery object.

Comment: What do you mean "get a select option"? Do you want to select it?

Answer (score 5):

You want the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

```
$('option:contains("option2")', 'select')
```

Comment: How would I use contains with the variable temp

Comment: @Chapsterj: `$('option:contains("' + temp + '")', 'select')` :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit per good point made by @Rocket::**

Try this if using values:

```
var val;

$( 'select' ).change(function(){
  val = $( 'option:selected', this ).val();
});
```

Try this if using the inner text:

```
var text;

$( 'select' ).change(function(){
  text = $( 'option:selected', this ).text();
});
```

Try this if grabbing the element:

```
var elem;

$( 'select' ).change(function(){
  elem = $( 'option:selected', this );
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `this` inside the `change`?

Comment: I know what `this` is. I mean, you should be using `$('option:selected', this)` instead, so that you only get the options from that select, and not all of them (if there were more). P.S. `$(this).val()` works fine, you don't need to get the `val()` of the option.

Comment: I wasn't making the assumption that there were multiple selects on the page. Just working with what I've got. $('option:selected', this) works, too, and is probably a better generic approach. Will update my answer. :)

Comment: Yep, just trying to be more generic, just in case.  Fix it now, to prevent bugs later :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/WEWcc/ **or** like Rocket mentioned without value attribute try this: http://jsfiddle.net/cbyTf/

Could write a custom filter-ish function. `:)`

**code**

```
var temp = "option2";
$(document).ready(function() {

        var filter = temp;
        $('option').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == filter) {
                alert($(this).val());
            } else {

            }
            $('select').val(filter);
        })

})​
```

**without value attribute**

```
var temp = "option2";
$(document).ready(function() {

        var filter = temp;
        $('option').each(function() {
            if ($(this).html() == filter) {
                alert($(this).html());
            } else {

            }

        })
   $('select').val(filter);
})​
```

Comment: Downvoter brother `:)` why you angry or not liking this; care to comment!

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but the OP wants the option returned as a jQuery element.  Also, why are you setting `$('select').val` in each loop iteration?

Comment: +1 @Rocket Thanks for comment man for your comment - could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/CvW5C/2/ you can +1 me lol if you want and I will chase our down voter

Comment: Umm, I just meant that the `$('select').val(filter);` should be *outside* of the `.each(`.

Comment: @Tats_innit: In you fiddle you just linked, `$('select').val(filter)` also does not return the option it returns the complete select element. Do `console.log($('select').val(filter));` to see.

Comment: @Tats_innit: As a side-note, the `.each` when compared to the `:contains` code executes progressively slower as more than 3 options are in the select. See fiddle for performance test: http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/ZAUR8/1/ At 3 options the speed is nearly the same but add 4,5 or 6 and it gets worse in the `each`.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Thanks bruv for the note `:)`